# Dafny, no duplicates in an array

Tags: z3, verification, dafny

in my program I have a `sorted` predicate.

```
forall i,j :: 0<=i<j<a.Length ==> a[i]<a[j]
```

I think just checking `<` rather than `<=` avoids duplications in the array but anyhow I  want to have a predicate that avoids duplications. 
I have used the  sorted predicate but checking for non-equality

```
forall i,j :: 0<=i<j<a.Length ==> a[i]!=a[j]
```

is there a better way to do that, by other keywords `in` or `exist` or `match` maybe if it is not deprecated?

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: @Theodore  shorter and if there is any reserved keyword or technique specific for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no builtin notion of "does not contain duplicates" in Dafny.

I think your way of expressing it is perfectly good. Another (longer, equivalent, but maybe slightly clearer) way would be

```
forall i, j | 0 <= i < a.Length && 0 <= j < a.Length && i != j :: a[i] != a[j]
```

Dafny easily shows that the two ways of writing it are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you. was wondering if you can help me with this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50514653/dafny-post-condition-does-not-hold-in-searching-for-element