# Proving non-linear traversal terminates in Dafny

Tags: dafny, termination, loop-invariant

I have an array of nats in Dafny that I want to traverse in a non-linear manner. To elucidate the problem: Consider an array such that (please ignore the syntax for now):

```
var links : array<nat>;

links := [1,2,5,4,0,3];
```

At a given index 'i', `links[i]` holds the index of the next element that must be considered. Here, let `i == 2 ==> links[i] == 5`. In the next iteration, the loop reads the value at index 5 which is 3 and so on till `links[i] == 0`.

I have implemented a while loop and some predicates that do not seem to prove termination.

The first predicate is that every element in the list is unique and no element is greater than the length of the loop. This is so because otherwise the array becomes circular. The predicate comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507869/dafny-no-duplicates-in-an-array).

`forall i, j | 0 <= i < links.Length && 0 <= j < links.Length && i != j :: links[i] != links[j]`

The second predicate is that there exists an element in the array which is 0. This is the terminating condition.

`exists q :: 0 <= q < links.Length && links[q] == 0`

The while loop iterates as follows:

```
qAct = links[0];

while(qAct != 0)
/* invariants and decreases ??? */
{
qAct = links[qAct];
}
```

The problem here is that qAct does not really decrease. To remedy that, I reasoned that the loop will never iterate more than its length, so I tried:

```
qAct = links[0];
var i : nat;
i := 0

while(qAct != 0 && i < links.Length)
/* this terminates */
decreases links.Length - i
{
qAct := links[qAct];
i := i + 1;
}
```

The reasoning is that, as per the design of the array, the number of elements cannot be greater than the length of the array. Therefore, the loop iterates at most links.Length times.

Is there way to prove the termination without using "i"? I also tried defining "i" as a ghost variable but I get an error saying "assignment to non-ghost variable is not allowed in this context." at `qAct := links[qAct]`.

A pen and paper proof with Hoare logic (and simple reasoning) is enough to show that qAct eventually converges to 0 due the second predicate. But Dafny fails to reason with this predicate.

Help from people experienced with Dafny is invaluable!

Comment: I think you might benefit from defining a derangement predicate to say that every element is not at its own index. Given [2 1 0] and if you start at 1 then it would not progress. 

You should use seq<nat> instead of array if you can since the verifier has an easier time working with immutable datastructures.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm actually just changing my code to use seq<nat>. Can you maybe give an example of a derangement predicate in Dafny? Although I understand what the predicate means but since I'm new to Dafny, it would be great if I can get an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the following definitions.

```
predicate derangement(s: seq<nat>) {
    forall i :: 0 <= i < |s| ==> s[i] != i
}

predicate permutation(s: seq<nat>) {
    forall i :: 0 <= i < |s| ==> i in s
}

method test(anotherPerm: seq<nat>)
  requires permutation(anotherPerm) && derangement(anotherPerm)
 {
    var tests := [2,0,1];
    var tests2 := [0,1,2];
    assert derangement(tests);
    assert permutation(tests);
    assert permutation(tests2);
    // assert !derangement(tests2); //this will actually not verify despite being true
}
```

In the end I kept working on it. I was able to get the following to verify.

```
predicate derangement(s: seq<nat>) {
    forall i :: 0 <= i < |s| ==> s[i] != i
}

predicate permutation(s: seq<nat>) {
    forall i :: 0 <= i < |s| ==> i in s
}

function multisetRange(n: nat): multiset<nat> {
    multiset(seq(n, i => i))
}

predicate distinct<A(==)>(s: seq<A>) {
    forall x,y :: x != y && 0 <= x <= y < |s| ==> s[x] != s[y]
}

method test() {
    var tests := [2,0,1];
    var tests2 := [0,1,2];
    var t4 := seq(3, i => i);
    var test3 := multisetRange(3);
    assert t4 == tests2;
    assert 0 in t4;
    assert 0 in test3;
    assert multiset(tests) == multisetRange(3);
    assert derangement(tests);
    assert permutation(tests);
    assert permutation(tests2);
    // assert !derangement(tests2);
}

method {:timelimit 40} end(links: seq<nat>)
    requires |links| > 0
    requires permutation(links)
    requires derangement(links)
    requires distinct(links)
{
    assume forall x :: x in links ==> 0 <= x < |links|;
    assume forall x :: x in links ==> multiset(links)[x] ==1;
    // assume multiset(links) == multisetRange(|links|);
    var qAct: nat := links[0];
    assert links[0] in links;
    var i : nat := 0;
    ghost var oldIndex := 0;
    ghost var indices: multiset<nat> := multiset{0};
    ghost var visited: multiset<nat> := multiset{};

    while qAct != 0
        invariant 0 <= oldIndex < |links|
        invariant qAct == links[oldIndex]
        invariant oldIndex in indices
        invariant qAct in links
        invariant indices == visited + multiset{0}
        invariant forall x :: x in visited ==> exists k :: 0 <= k < |links| && links[k] == x && k in indices
        invariant qAct !in visited
        invariant 0 <= qAct < |links|
        decreases multiset(links) - visited
    {
        ghost var oldVisit := visited;
        ghost var oldqAct := qAct;
        ghost var oldOldIndex := oldIndex;
        oldIndex := qAct;
        visited := visited + multiset{qAct};
        indices := indices + multiset{qAct};
        assert oldqAct in visited;
        assert forall x :: x in visited ==> exists k :: 0 <= k < |links| && links[k] == x && k in indices by  {
            forall x | x in visited 
                ensures exists k :: 0 <= k < |links| && links[k] == x && k in indices
            {
                if x == oldqAct {
                    assert links[oldOldIndex] == oldqAct;
                    assert exists k :: 0 <= k < |links| && links[k] == x && k in indices;
                }else {
                    assert x in oldVisit;
                    assert exists k :: 0 <= k < |links| && links[k] == x && k in indices;
                }
            }
        }
        qAct := links[qAct];
        i := i + 1;
    }
}
```

Ideally you should either move the assume's into the method requirement or better yet define lemmas that ensure those statements based on the links being a permutation.

Comment: I also kept working on it... I did a similar predicate like distinct. Your idea with derangement worked correctly but I think this idea with visited is what can help me complete this. I'll accept this answer even though it may not directly help me. There are many ideas here that I can use. Much thanks!!